# Binary search tree - Iterative check for height

Tags: c, stack, height, binary-search-tree, non-recursive

So, I'm having a bit of problem. I know how to traverse tree, using recursion or not, using stack or not. But, I also want to track height of every leaf, and if height(or depth) is less than given argument to print that leaf. Here is my code using stack:

```
void PrintLevelIter(struct tNode* tree, int h1){
    if(h1==0){
        printf("%d ",tree->info);
        return;
    }
    struct sNode *stek = NULL;
    push(&stek,tree);

    struct tNode* current = tree;


    while(!isEmptyStack(stek)){
        pop(&stek);
        printf("%d ",current->info);
        if(current->left != NULL && current->right != NULL){
            if(Depth(current) < h1){
                push(&stek, current);
            }
            else return;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe because of my stack implementation? Here is code:

```
struct sNode{
    struct tNode* t;
    struct sNode* next;
};

/*Funkcije za stek*/
void push(struct sNode** top, struct tNode* t){
    struct sNode* newNode = (struct sNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));
    if(newNode==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    newNode->t = t;
    newNode->next = (*top);
    (*top) = newNode;
}

int isEmptyStack(struct sNode* top){
    return top==NULL;
}

struct tNode* pop(struct sNode** top){
    struct tNode* res;
    struct sNode* sTop;

    if(isEmptyStack(*top))
        printf("Stack is empty!");
    else{
        sTop = *top;
        res = sTop->t;
        *top = sTop->next;
        free(top);

    }
    return res;
}
```

The thing is, my output gives me only root value, nothing else. Does anyone know where I'm making a mistake? Or mistakes :)?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly your issue, input and expected result would be helpfull in this case, but this `if(Depth(current) < h1){
                push(&stek, current);
            }
            else return;`  does not look correct. why `return` ? you exit the function before all the tree is traversed

Comment: `if(isEmptyStack(*top)) printf("Stack is empty!");` is a problem.  Should this occur, "Stack is empty!" is sent to `stdout`, but since output is typically buffered, nothing is printed _yet_.  Then code returns uninitialized `res` with undefined behavior results and maybe never prints the message.  Better to 1) `fprintf(stderr...`, or 2) `fflush(stdout)` after the print or 3) add a `'\n'` or 4) simply exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you don't change the value of `current` inside the loop, `pop(&stek)` should be `current = pop(&stek)`
2. `return` should be `continue`, it's not a recursion, return will exit the function before all the tree is traversed
3. you need to push the node children not the node himself

   ```
   while (!isEmptyStack(stek))
   {
       current = pop(&stek);

       if (current->left != NULL)
           push(&stek, current->left);
       if (current->right != NULL)
           push(&stek, current->right);

       if (Depth(current) < h1)
           printf("%d ",current->info);
   }
   ```
4. as @chux said, `pop` should return `NULL` if stack is empty